# Jquery Mobile enlarge images posted through PHP

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, image-enlarge

I need help please. I am developing an application using Jquery Mobile and PHP. I am retrieving data from a MySQL database. I was able to pull the data including images. I need the user to be able to click on any image and the image is enlarged. I used PHP to loop through the rows and create popup divisions for the images to popup. This is working perfectly on a laptop but on a mobile device, it is very slow and the popup images created are very large and much wider than the normal mobile web app width.

Please refer to the code below and thank you for your time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" /> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <section id="main" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true">

        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="theHeader">

        <h1>Header Title</h1>

        <a href="/" data-rel="back">Go Back</a>

    </header>


    <article data-role="content">

    <?php

        $con = mysql_connect('db','user','password');
        if (!$con)
        {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("db");


        $sql = "select * from table";


        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $ii = 0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
                echo('<div class="ui-grid-a">');

                echo('<div class="ui-block-a"><h6>'.$row['col1'].'</h6><h6>'.$row['col2'].'</h6><h6>'.$row['col3'].'</h6></div>');

                echo('<a href="#popup'.$ii.'" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="http://..../images/' . $row["imageName"] .'" alt="' . $row["imageName"] .'" style="height: 180px; width:130px;"></a>');

                echo('<div data-role="popup" id="popup'.$ii.'" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" src="http://..../images/' . $row["imageName"] .'" style="max-height:512px;" alt="'.$row["imageName"].'"></div>');

                echo('</div>');
                echo('<hr />');
                $ii++;
         }

        mysql_close($con);

    ?>

    </article>

    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="theFooter">

        <h1>Footer</h1>

    </footer>
    </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Have tried this? http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/#Photolightbox

Comment: This is different as I am using PHP to load the images and generating JQMobile popup divs inside PHP. The images are working but it is very slow and the popup divs are enlarged crazy.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can have small pictures so when the user clics them they are enlarged without quitting the site in Jquery Mobile.

This is what i use, i hope it helps you.

```
                <a href='#popupPic1' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='fade'><img class='popphoto' src='./img/rest/$pic1' alt='' height='90' width='32%' style='max-width:200px;'></a>
                <a href='#popupPic2' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='fade'><img class='popphoto' src='./img/rest/NO_es.jpg' alt='' height='90' width='32%' style='max-width:200px;'></a>
                <a href='#popupPic3' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='fade'><img class='popphoto' src='./img/rest/NO_es.jpg' alt='' height='90' width='32%' style='max-width:200px;'></a>

                <div data-role='popup' id='popupPic1' data-overlay-theme='a' data-theme='d' data-corners='false'>
                    <a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-theme='a' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'>Close</a><img class='popphoto' src='./img/rest/$pic1' style='max-height:512px;' alt=''></div>
                <div data-role='popup' id='popupPic2' data-overlay-theme='a' data-theme='d' data-corners='false'>
                    <a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-theme='a' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'>Close</a><img class='popphoto' src='./img/rest/NO_es.jpg' style='max-height:512px;' alt=''></div>
                <div data-role='popup' id='popupPic3' data-overlay-theme='a' data-theme='d' data-corners='false'>
                    <a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-theme='a' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'>Close</a><img class='popphoto' src='./img/rest/NO_es.jpg' style='max-height:512px;' alt=''></div>
```

Obiously just fix the SRC from the IMG you want it to load.

If it helped you, give me Thumbs up.

Thanks

Comment: I am referring to using PHP to load the images and generating JQMobile popup divs inside PHP. The images are working but it is very slow and the popup divs are enlarged crazy.

Comment: Consider to specify max-width as for max-height.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `pophoto` class. This class is one of the standard popup element classes in `jqm`.

Perhaps the [jquery mobile documention](http://jquerymobile.com/) has more useful information which you can use for your project.

Comment: could you please add a bit more Information to answer the question?